# Tableau server error - field not found, does not exist in database

Tags: tableau-api

I am using Tableau version 8.0.0. When i publish the report in Live server i get the following error **"TableauException: Field '[ACCOUNT_SCHEDULE_FACT].[DATE_DM]', which is included in a join clause, does not exist. Unable to connect to the server ". I have verified that the column DATE_DM exists in the table ACCOUNT_SCHEDULE_FACT. The server is up and running. The join condition in the report has been verified even for case sensitive issue. 
However when i publish the same report in Development Server or when i check it in desktop (without publishing)  it  does not throw any error and works smoothly. The custom sql from tableau has been executed in our sql server database and it returns correct number of rows. Can somebody point out why this error is occurring or whether there is any workaround for this problem? 
Thanks and regards
Gautam

Comment: Sounds like something is different between your production and development environments. Maybe there is a network or firewall issue, or your production database is different than your development database. If you can't resolve it, try contacting tableau support. They're usually pretty helpful if you can give them enough detail to describe the problem.

Comment: Has your Production version of Tableau server been restarted since the field was added to the database?  It could be operating off an out-of-date dictionary.

Comment: What Alex said. There is probably a mismatch between your dev and production databases. Can you open the production workbook in Tableau Desktop without any errors?